# How to catch an event in controller which is thrown by an directive in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm having some trouble sending and catching events in Angular.

Consider this plunker: [Plunk..](http://plunker.co/edit/KDWxXIeeLeTfBPfl6NNE?p=preview)

As you can see I have two controllers and a directive. The directive 'lives' in controller 1. When something happens in the directive, I want to catch this event in controller 2. As you can see in the plunk, nothing is logged to the console; the event is not catched.

I've also tried to use a service. In this scenario I created a method on the service and when this method is called, I throw the event. Just like in the Plunk, I listen for the event in Controller 2, but this also didn't work.

Where it all comes down to is that I want to invoke a method on another controller..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you visit a route, the associated controller (and a $scope) are (re)created.

Since you mentioned that Controller 2 is associated with a route, it will only exist when you visit that route (as @Ajay and @Stewie already mentioned), so you can't catch an event in that controller.

I suggest you create a service with some API/methods to do the following:

- record that an event triggered
- check to see if an event triggered
- clear an event

Your directive would call the method to record the trigger.
Your Controller 2 would call the check method when it is created (and then probably call the clear method if it finds the trigger set).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I understand you correct, you suggest to create a $watch on Controller 2 on a variable/property of the service?

Comment: @Martijn, a $watch will only trigger if a change is detected (and when it first initializes).  That may work for your scenario, but it might not.  If the event already triggered before controller 2 is created, then simply call a method on the service as part of controller 2's initialization to determine if the event happened.  If the event may happen while controller 2 exists, then also use a $watch.

Comment: In my scenario, I don't think Controller 2 exists when the event is triggered. So you suggest to `simply call a method on the service as part of controller 2's initialization to determine if the event happened`. I don't know exactly what you mean by this. Could you explain that a little bit more?

Comment: @Martijn, sure:  `function Ctrl2($scope, 'MyService') { if (MyService.eventTriggered()) { ... }`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't get it to work. I've created a service with a variable (triggered) and a function. The directive calls this function and the function sets triggered to true. But how is Controller 2 notified without using a $watch?

Comment: @Martijn, when Ctrl2 is created (when you change routes), the Ctrl2 constructor function will execute.  That function should call MyService.eventTriggered() which should return the value of variable `triggered`.  Ctrl2 is essentially asking the service if the variable is set, rather than watching the variable (since in previous discussions, it sounds like the variable gets set before Ctrl2 exists).

Comment: I've done exactly what you suggested, but I can't get it to work. In the debugger is see that `triggered` is set to true, but the function returning triggered (`isEventTriggered()`) isn't invoked and I do have `if (EventDispatcherService.isEventTriggered()){..}` in the 'root' of Controller 2. But.. when I browse to the page that has Controller 2 attached, then I see the function is called. Is it what you suggest to perform a redirect when I set `triggered` to true?

Answer (score 2):

In you Plunker, second controller (`SecondController`) is registered, but it is never actually initialized. So that's why your listener never logs the event.

It's not clear how, where and when you are using using your second controller, but if you initialize it with either ng-view (through routes) or ng-controller, than its listener will observe the event.

[PLUNKER](http://plunker.co/edit/NG4KjxwReF77BCipu3bi?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have Controller 2 registered in my routes (I couldn't get plunker working with routes and templates). But all my controllers are configured in the routes. In this case I am viewing page1.html (with controller 1) which as the `foo` directive. The foo directive refers to foo.hmtl. When on foo.html something happens, I want to raise an event and I want to catch this event in Controller 2, which is not visible(/loaded?) at the moment, but is registered t the routes.

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal is trying to say that when you're using routeProvider to specify the controllers that will run on each page, than at any given moment, the only loaded controller is the one that is specified under current route. Meaning, controllers are not loaded all the time. If route `/some/route` is defined to use `SomeController` than `SomeController` will be loaded only when that route is active.